# Куда будут добавлены итерируемые элементы Set?

Tags: javascript, set

Я читаю [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%C2%A0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80.%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%20(%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20null)%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20Set%C2%A0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC.) и не очень понимаю что имеется в виду:

> При  передаче итерируемого объекта все его элементы **будут добавлены в новый набор.** Иначе (или при null) новый Set будет пустым.

Что значит добавлены в новый набор?

```
let set = new Set([
   ['hello'],
   ['my name is', ['apple', 'orange', 'melon']], //массив внутри должен стать отдельным эл-том??
   ['Lena']
]);
```

Все остается по-прежнему. Ничего в никакой "новый набор" не переходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Set  это набор. Свой массив массивов временный передаешь в конструктор Set и получаешь в наборе все массивы

Answer (score 1):

[`new Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) - создает новый объект. Если в конструктор передали какую-либо коллекцию - все элементы этой коллекции будут добавлены в созданный объект.

Для примера из вопроса:

1. передали коллекцию:

   ```
   [
       ['hello'],
       ['my name is', ['apple', 'orange', 'melon']], //массив внутри должен стать отдельным эл-том??
       ['Lena']
   ]
   ```
2. в коллекции три элемента:

   1. `['hello']`
   2. `['my name is', ['apple', 'orange', 'melon']]`
   3. `['Lena']`
3. Эти три элемента добавились в объект, который был создан внутри конструктора `Set`